# angular 6 unit testing on http service errors

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I get errors while I m trying to test one of my services.

The service has a method that makes a POST request on the server and then returns a data, yes I know why POST and not GET.

I need to say that I can't use the authentication service because using my login and then I get the tokens from the server. 
Since I can't log in to get the token all the requests are not valid.

How to unit test HTTP calls without making requests on the server, just using local data that simulates the server response.

my service is this.

#### inventory.service.ts

```
  /**
   * GETS THE INVENTORY DATA.
   * @returns Observable of inventory data from the server.
   */
  getInventoryData<T>() {

    const options = { headers: this.getHeaders() };
    const body: AdditionFiltersEntity = this.shared.getAdditionFilters({});
    const url = `${this.shared.baseUrl}/inventory`;

    return this.http.post(url, body, options).pipe(
      tap(val => console.log(`BEFORE MAP: ${val}`)),
      map(res => res.json()),
      catchError(e => this.shared.handleError(e))
    );

  }
```

The problem is because I have the `catchError(e => this.shared.handleError(e))`
this checks if the response has errors in my case I have "UNAUTHORIZED" statusText

In my case, I have all the time this type of error on all HTTP tests.

> status: 401, ok: false, statusText: "UNAUTHORIZED"
>   but this is ok since I m unit testing I can't pass the authorization part.

My unit test file is this.

#### inventory.service.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

// Modules
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

// Services
import { InventoryService } from './inventory.service';
import { HelpersService } from '@app-services/helpers/helpers.service';
import { MediatorService } from '@app-services/mediator/mediator.service';
import { AuthService } from '@app-services/auth/auth.service';
import { StorageService } from '@app-services/storage/storage.service';

// Models
import { InventoryEntity } from '@app-models/inventory';



describe('InventoryService', () => {

  // let service: InventoryService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let auth: AuthService;
  // let user: User;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpModule, MatSnackBarModule, RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule,
      HttpClientTestingModule, BrowserAnimationsModule
    ],
      providers: [
        InventoryService, AuthService, HelpersService, MediatorService, StorageService
      ]
    });


    httpMock  = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    auth      = TestBed.get(AuthService);
    localStorage.setItem('store_ids', JSON.stringify([1])); // just set a test id so we gonna get some kind data.

  });


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.compileComponents().catch(error => console.error(error));
  }));

  it('should be created', inject([InventoryService], (service: InventoryService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  // This is where I get the errors
  fit('Should get inventory data', inject([InventoryService], async (service: InventoryService) => {

    await service.getInventoryData().subscribe( (res: InventoryEntity[]) => {

      // get array first element keys.
      const evaluationKeys = ['brand', 'color_code', 'color_tag', 'family', 'frame_size', 'gender', 'provider', 'quantity', 'tag'];
      const keys = Object.keys(res[0]);

      expect(keys).toEqual(evaluationKeys);

    });

  }));


});
```

- Can someone explain to me how to make unit tests on HTTP calls like this one
  `service.getInventoryData().subscribe`
- And how to deal with the authentication part. 
  the authentication is where all my tests fail.
- if I need to use mock data, how to make this, can someone show me an example?

#### The response should give me this data.

```
[
  {
    'brand': 'brand-1',
    'color_code': '593',
    'color_tag': 'SILVER',
    'family': 'SOL',
    'frame_size': '54x16x140',
    'gender': 'Unisexe',
    'provider': 'hgg',
    'quantity': 82,
    'tag': '44554'
  }, {
    'brand': 'brand-2',
    'color_code': 'MAU1O1',
    'color_tag': 'BLACK',
    'family': 'SOL',
    'frame_size': '54x17x140',
    'gender': 'Unisexe',
    'provider': 'hgg',
    'quantity': 98,
    'tag': '45445'
  }
]
```

Comment: remove `HttpClientModule` from your testbed configuration imports

Comment: Hi, @Joey Gough I have removed this, is not working. I have the same error from the response, it says I am UNAUTHORIZED to make any requests on the server. all the requests has to be valid first since I can't log in to get a token from the server, I get this errors.

Comment: You need to decide - its either integration/e2e test (hit server) or unit tests (mock responses). In UT there is no such problems as you provide whatever you need by yourself.

Comment: @Antoniossss is unit testing

Comment: Then why are you hitting real server?

Comment: In reality I dont even know what is the difference.

Comment: The difference is, if I run it offline it wont work. Moreover, using real, protected endpoints causes troubles like you are facing - having proper mocked backend you would be able to "authenticate" yourself without any 3rd parties.

Comment: @Antoniossss I just started to use testing in my project so I want to test the inventory service

Comment: Read official angular guide onto how to test http services - its straight forward. Yo make request, then you mock the response - application will see no difference. https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing-http-services

Comment: I m so noob on unit testing and all testing paradigms. so I think I m doing unit testing.

Comment: Read official guide I have pasted for you https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing-http-services.

Comment: I was there but the problem is how to deal with this, have a part in my code that makes HTTP post request and I need to test this, I don't know how to test this while I need to authenticate first because my app requires authentication before make any request.

Comment: @Antoniossss what should I do on this case base on your experience.
should I test HTTP calls only on E2E tests? and for the unit testing just provide the data hardcoded?

Comment: Did you read the link? On unit testing you should mock responses. You want to test cases like bad requests, server offline etc. This cannot be done (easily) with real endpoints thus you mock it. Use real backend on integration or e2e testing.

Comment: As for unit testing eg services in scope of logic, and not handling http communication stuff, I would personally don't use http client at all. But that requires your code to be clean so eg you can test your bussiness method by directly providing input data, not by "mocking" or even performing http requests. Http testing backend is very convinient to eg test your interceptors, auto token refreshes, auto request retrying etc, and to investigate (maybe this is most important) what requests are beeing made by your client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you should not have to worry about your http call, when *unit testing*. I would expect that the API response is tested seperately on server side. While testing the service, my task would be to validate that my service does what it should do, **correctly**, assuming, that the response is available. If not, you could possibly, test if your service handles the error response correctly). you can read more about it on [jasmine docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)

So, in this case i will usually mock my response. you could use a  jasmine`spy` to spy on the service call like `spy.On(service, 'getInventoryData').and.returnValues(of({your json});`.

Or, if you feel you have a very big json, store it in a local resource folder for example: app/test/resources/response1.json` and then import it in your spec like:

`const response: any = require('../test/resources/response1.json');`